# Print Variavel Json PHP

Tags: php, json

Tenho um json

`$data= '[
    {
        "opa": "maam",
        "clik": "7026981995",
        "pt": 123,
        "aaab": [{
            "ttt": "1.22",
            "tt": [{
                "aaa2": 1.2277,
                "aaa122": 19811225
            }]
        }]
    },
    {
        "opaa": "maam1",
        "clik1": "7026981995",
        "pt1": 123,
        "aaa11": [{
            "ttt1": "1.222",
            "tt1": [{
                "aaa1": 1.2277,
                "aaa3": 19811225
            }]
        }]
    }
]'`

Preciso imprimi-lo na tela, da mesma forma que está na variavel, tentei

`echo json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);`

Mas, é impresso um amontoado, não ficando legivel.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido

`echo '<pre>'.print_r(json_decode($data), true).'</pre>';`